# Integrate - google hotel finder - web application

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried to find to Google hotel finder API to integrate into my application. I couldn't find it. Can someone help me in this. Please let me know if there is any another service like this.

Thanks.

Comment: jlivni is absolutely right. You have to use Google Places API or you can use other API's like Foursquare also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Hotel API, but you can use the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/) with the category limited to 'lodging'.  If this is not what you're looking for, please provide more specific examples of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: In google hotel finder, you select area on the map and it shows hotels in that. I would like to have that list of hotels when I select a specific area on the map.

Comment: You can't do this exact functionality, but you can do something similar using the Places API:  Just have a radius larger than the drawn shape, and then run your own point-in-polygon method to restrict the results.  Note that only 20 results are delivered by the Places API, and many might be in the radius but outside the shape, so YMMV.  More Places API queries with smaller radii might help.